# Finding a short path using $(0.99n)!$ permutations

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, oc.optimization-and-control

Suppose I have $n$ points $x_1,\dots,x_n$ that are all independent uniform samples in the unit square, and I'd like to find a short path (in terms of Euclidean length) that touches all of them (a traveling salesman path, in other words).  Obviously, one (inefficient) way to do this would be to write down every permutation of $\{1,\dots,n\}$, record the length of the path that visits the $x_i$'s in that order, and select the permutation that gave the shortest path.

Now suppose that, before the $x_i$'s are sampled, I am allowed to write down not *all* $n!$ permutations, but only a subset of permutations of size (say) $(0.99n)!$.  Is there a "clever" choice of permutations that is likely to contain a good (i.e. short) path (in the sense of Euclidean length) through the $x_i$'s, in the limit as $n$ becomes large?

Comment: What is your measure of how good a path is?

Comment: I want the path to have a short Euclidean length.  Presumably I'd need to search all $n!$ permutations to get the *shortest* path, so I'd just like the Euclidean length to be "not too much longer" in some probabilistic sense. (made some minor edits to the original question to try to clarify this)

Comment: Yes, it was clear that you wanted it to be short. How are you measuring whether a path of a given shortness is good?

Comment: @DouglasZare oh, I see -- well, given that the length of the shortest path scales proportionally to $\sqrt{n}$, I'd like a path whose length is less than $c\sqrt{n}$, for some value of $c$.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Did you check, or is there an obstruction to checking, that picking your subset at random usually works?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is highly unlikely. Take any such system $S$ of permutations. Take any configuration of points obtained by sampling and note that we can also get it with the points re-enumerated in any way. Now let us look at how many reasonably short path enumerations are there at all. For each short path, there is a sequence of integers $a_1,\dots,a_{n-1}$ with sum $\le Cn$ such that the $k$-th step jump is at most $a_k n^{-1/2}$. There are only exponentially (in $n$) many such sequences. Now, for a typical configuration, the number of points in any disk of radius $Rn^{-1/2}$ is at most $CR^2\log n$ (the exponential tail estimate for the Poisson distribution), so at each step we have just $Ca_k^2\log n$ choices at most, giving at most $e^{Cn}(\log n)^n$ permutations total that can work in principle. Call that set $K$. We must have $S\pi\cap K\ne\varnothing$ for most permutations $\pi$, whence $|S||K|\ge n!/2$. So, we can have only $(C\log n)^n$ gain (actually even less; I guess the exponential gain is the right one), which is quite short of $n^{0.01n}$ you want.